# Multi-threading and Sockets in Python: 'Existing connection forcibly closed' error

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

If you want to skip to the best explantion, skip to the very end of the question

--------ORIGINAL QUESTION---------

I created a small Python client/server project and each of the connection sides uses the same class.

```
from channel import Channel
import time
import constants
import sys
is_py2 = sys.version[0] == '2'
if is_py2:
    import Queue as queue
else:
    import queue as queue

class OneSide:
  def __init__(self, address1, address2, target1, target2):
    self.inQueue1 = queue.Queue()
    self.channel1 = Channel(address1,target1,self.inQueue1)
    time.sleep(.500)
    self.inQueue2 = queue.Queue()
    self.channel2 = Channel(address2,target2,self.inQueue2)

  def close(self):
    self.channel1.stopListening();
    self.channel2.stopListening();

  def from1(self, msg):
    self.channel1.write(msg)

  def from2(self, msg):
    self.channel2.write(msg)

  def read1(self):
    while not self.inQueue1.empty():
      print(self.inQueue1.get())

  def read2(self):
    while not self.inQueue2.empty():
      print(self.inQueue2.get())
```

And for completeness sake, I'll include Channel

```
import threading
import socket
import sys
is_py2 = sys.version[0] == '2'
if is_py2:
    import Queue as queue
else:
    import queue as queue

class Channel:
  def __init__(self, address, target, outQueue):
    self.address = address
    self.target = target
    self.connection = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.connection.bind(address)
    self.connection.settimeout(5.0)
    self.outQueue = outQueue
####THIS IS THE PROBLEM####
    self.serverThread = threading.Thread(target=self.serverFunction)
    self.startListening()
####THIS IS THE PROBLEM####

  def startListening(self):
    self.running = True
    self.serverThread.start()

  def stopListening(self):
    print("Shutting down server thread port {}".format(self.address[1]))
    self.running = False

  def serverFunction(self):
    # time.sleep(.100) # sleep 100 ms
    print("Server thread started on port {}".format(self.address[1]))
    while self.running:
      try:
        self.outQueue.put(self.read(1024))
      except socket.timeout:
        #no error; this can occur if the read times out
        pass
      except Exception as e:
        # must have been forced close
        print("Server thread failed on port {}".format(self.address[1]))
        print("  Error: {}".format(e))
        self.running = False
    self.connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.connection.close()
    print("Closed server thread port {}".format(self.address[1]))

  def write(self, bytes):
    self.connection.sendto(bytes, self.target)

  def read(self, bufferSize):
    bytesAddressPair = self.connection.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    return bytearray(message)
```

I wrote one main.py file that creates two objects and runs them against each other.

```
from oneside import OneSide
import time

c1 = OneSide(("127.0.0.1",2000),("127.0.0.1",2001),("127.0.0.1",1000),("127.0.0.1",1001));
time.sleep(.500)
c2 = OneSide(("127.0.0.1",1000),("127.0.0.1",1001),("127.0.0.1",2000),("127.0.0.1",2001));
time.sleep(.500)

c1.from1("bytes1")
c1.from2("bytes2")

c2.from1("reverse1")
c2.from2("reverse2")

c1.read1()
c1.read2()

c2.read1()
c2.read2()

c2.close()
c1.close()
```

This code runs with no problem. I wanted to run two instances separately so I created two separate main files and I ran them individually.

```
from oneside import OneSide
import time

c1 = OneSide(("127.0.0.1",2000),("127.0.0.1",2001),("127.0.0.1",1000),("127.0.0.1",1001));
time.sleep(.500)

c1.from1("bytes1")
c1.from2("bytes2")

c1.read1()
c1.read2()

c1.close()
```

When I run this, however, I get an error. It happens if I run just one or both.

```
Error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Questions: Why is this happening at all? How do I fix it? Why doesn't it happen when I run both servers concurrently?

----ADDITIONAL DETAIL----

I have pressed on with the connection working betwee two OneSide objects and it's bee successful, but now I've started running it in a multi-threaded way and it comes up with the same error.

----FINAL EDIT----
Please note that I am STILL looking for an explantion as I can't seem to find anything explaining why threading and sockets don't mix. Nevertheless, this is what I have found.

I built this program a piece at a time and at one stage I setup Channel to have a threaded "server" function that would read data and print it out. I morphed that to read data and shove it in a queue that I could read in a different thread. Later, I puth that reader into a thread and all along the socket was created in the main thread.

Once I cottoned on to the idea that a socket should not be accessed outside of the thread it was created in, things got better. I took my multi-threaded  STOneSide (safe-thread OneSide) and created the Channel inside of the thread

```
    def startup(self, channel_id, address, target):
        self.channels[channel_id] = Channel(address, target, self.queues[channel_id])
        port = self.addresses[channel_id][1]
        safe_print("Port {} Stage 1".format(port))

        while not self.states[channel_id] == CONNECTED:
            self.states[channel_id] = STAGE1
...
```

I was still getting the error, but I was able to connect occasionally. I still didn't realize that the channel was also creating a thread. Once I did that, I removed the thread and temporarily revised my code so I could directly read from the threaded function in STOneSide where the Channel and socket were created. Bingo. Everyone connected. No issues.

```
#From STOneSide
    def read_all(self, channel_id):
        self.channels[channel_id].read_all()
        output = []
        while not self.queues[channel_id].empty():
            output.append(self.queues[channel_id].get())
        return output

# From Channel
  def read_all(self):
    running = True
    while running:
      try:
        self.outQueue.put(self.read(1024))
      except socket.timeout:
        #end of all data
        running = False
        pass
      except Exception as e:
        # must have been forced close
        safe_print("Server thread failed on port {}".format(self.address[1]))
        safe_print("  Error: {}".format(e))
        running = False
```

Okay, so I know what the problem is and how to fix it. I am still offering a checkmark to anyone who can show me some documentation explaining why the socket should not be accessed from a different thread.

Comment: What is ``oneside``? How is ``Channel`` relevant?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  UDP sockets do not make "connections".  There's nothing to forcibly close.  Are you sure `OneSide` is using UDP?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi OneSide uses Channel and main uses OneSide.

Comment: @TimRoberts my understanding is that because I am using socket.SOCK_DGRAM it is a UDP connection. You are right that during a send operation the UDP connection is created for limited time, but on the server side I still have to listen for things that come in. For that I have a loop and the loop is timing out every 5 seconds when there is no traffic so I can gracefully close.

Comment: Well, *how* is it that "OneSide uses Channel and main uses OneSide"? There are some gaps for which we can do nothing but guess at the moment. Can you please [edit] your question to include the missing parts of the traceback and expand the code to a [mcve]?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi apologies. My original write up contained two copies of the main instead of one copy of OneSide. Hope this helps